# Using bindData method outside of controller

Tags: grails

I was wondering if anyone had an idea for the best way to provide the
functionality of bindData() outside of my grails controllers. In my current
project I have created several groovy classes to model objects returned by
an api. In these classes I have a static method that parses xml and returns
a List of objects of the class. I would like to skip all the type casting
nonsense by using the bindData method in these classes. Any suggestions on
how to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

I was looking for a similar solution, to use bindData in a service class. I found a solution in [JT's blog](http://jts-blog.com/?p=215). The solution is basically to import:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.metaclass.BindDynamicMethod
```

then add this to your code:

```
def foo = new Foo()
BindDynamicMethod bind = new BindDynamicMethod()
def args =  [ foo, params, [exclude:['name', 'mail']] ] // for example
bind.invoke( foo, 'bind', (Object[])args)
```

The (Object[]) cast is necessary du to Groovy/Java compatability. (Groovy is treating the ‘args’ object as an ArrayList, not an array of Objects.)

Comment: If this is used in a spinned off thread (at least with executor-plugin), it seems to fail because of missing request:
**java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request...**